# x86-64 assembler for polymorphic call

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, x86-64

I have the C++ code:

```
int main(){
    M* m;

    O* o = new IO();
    H* h = new H("A");

    if(__rdtsc() % 5 == 0){
        m = new Y(o, h);
    }
    else{
        m = new Z(o, h);
    }

    m->my_virtual();

    return 1;
}
```

where the virtual call is represented by this asm:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [x]  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]  
mov         rcx,qword ptr [x]  
call        qword ptr [rax]
```

It is one more line than I was expecting for the vtable method invoccation. Are all four of the ASM lines specific to the polymorphic call?

How do the above four lines read pseudo-ly?

This is the complete ASM and C++ (the virtual call is made right at the end):

```
int main(){
 add         byte ptr [rax-33333334h],bh  
 rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0A8h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
    M* x;

    o* o = new IO();
 mov         ecx,70h  
 call        operator new (013F6B7A70h) 
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rax  
 cmp         qword ptr [rsp+40h],0  
 je          main+4Fh (013F69687Fh)  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+40h]  
 call        IO::IO (013F6814F6h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0B0h],rax  
 jmp         main+5Bh (013F69688Bh)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0B0h],0  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0B0h]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+38h]  
 mov         qword ptr [o],rax  
    H* h = new H("A");
 mov         ecx,150h  
 call        operator new (013F6B7A70h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+50h],rax  
 cmp         qword ptr [rsp+50h],0  
 je          main+0CEh (013F6968FEh)  
 lea         rax,[rsp+58h]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+80h],rax  
 lea         rdx,[ec_table+11Ch (013F7C073Ch)]  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+80h]  
 call        std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > (013F681104h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0B8h],rax  
 mov         rdx,qword ptr [rsp+0B8h]  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+50h]  
 call        H::H (013F6826A3h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0C0h],rax  
 jmp         main+0DAh (013F69690Ah)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0C0h],0  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0C0h]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+48h],rax  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+48h]  
 mov         qword ptr [h],rax  

    if(__rdtsc() % 5 == 0){
 rdtsc  
 shl         rdx,20h  
 or          rax,rdx  
 xor         edx,edx  
 mov         ecx,5  
 div         rax,rcx  
 mov         rax,rdx  
 test        rax,rax  
 jne         main+175h (013F6969A5h)  
        x = new Y(o, h);
 mov         ecx,18h  
 call        operator new (013F6B7A70h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+90h],rax  
 cmp         qword ptr [rsp+90h],0  
 je          main+14Ah (013F69697Ah)  
 mov         r8,qword ptr [h]  
 mov         rdx,qword ptr [o]  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+90h]  
 call        Y::Y (013F681B4Fh)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0C8h],rax  
 jmp         main+156h (013F696986h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0C8h],0  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0C8h]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+88h],rax  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+88h]  
 mov         qword ptr [x],rax  
    }
    else{
 jmp         main+1DCh (013F696A0Ch)  
        x = new Z(o, h);
 mov         ecx,18h  
 call        operator new (013F6B7A70h)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0A0h],rax  
 cmp         qword ptr [rsp+0A0h],0  
 je          main+1B3h (013F6969E3h)  
 mov         r8,qword ptr [h]  
 mov         rdx,qword ptr [o]  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0A0h]  
 call        Z::Z (013F68160Eh)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0D0h],rax  
 jmp         main+1BFh (013F6969EFh)  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0D0h],0  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+0D0h]  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+98h],rax  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+98h]  
 mov         qword ptr [x],rax  
    }

    x->my_virtual();
 mov         rax,qword ptr [x]  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]  
 mov         rcx,qword ptr [x]  
 call        qword ptr [rax]  

    return 1;
 mov         eax,1  
}
```

Comment: Line 3 updates `rcx`, not `rax`.

Comment: @xxbbcc excuse me :) its late

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking at unoptimized code:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [x]       ; load rax with object pointer
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]     ; load rax with the vtable pointer
mov         rcx,qword ptr [x]       ; load rcx with the object pointer (the 'this' pointer)
call        qword ptr [rax]         ; call through the vtable slot for the virtual function
```

Comment: +1. I was wondering about the role of `rcx` - I forgot about the `this` pointer.

Comment: Just wondered why you said its un-optimized code? Whats the optimized version for the polymorphic call?

Comment: @user997112: For example, I'd expect an optimizer to recognize that `rax` already has the pointer to `x`, so it need not reload it.  The optimized sequence might look like `mov rcx, rax; mov rax,[rax], call qword ptr [rax]`. However, if you turn on the optimizer, you'll probably get something different because the codegen for the stuff leading up to the virtual call will likely change quite a bit and register use choices might be different (though the calling convention requires `rcx` to have the object pointer when the virtual call is made).

Comment: @MichaelBurr like Ben Voight has put in the first part of his answer?

Comment: @user997112: I was thinking more like Ben's second example without the first line because the optimizer would know that `rax` already contains the object pointer from one of the code sequences that did the `new` operation. However, since the optimizer would also modify those sequences, the details of how the virtual call ends up would change, too.  So who knows - it might actually end up like Ben's first example.

Answer (score 4):

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [x]
```

get the address pointed to by x

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]
```

get the address of the vtable for x's class (using rax we just worked out). Put it in rax

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [x]
```

get the pointer x and put it in rcx, so it can be used as the "this" pointer in the called function.

```
call        qword ptr [rax]
```

call the function using the address from the vtable we found earlier (no offset as it is the first virtual function).

There are definitely shorter ways to do it, which the compiler might use if you switch optimizations on (e.g. only get [x] once).

Updated with more info from Ben Voigt

Comment: Its stage 2 I dont quite understand. How exactly does that command access the vtable?

Comment: @user997112: Evidently the vtable pointer is stored at offset zero in your particular layout.

Comment: @TheDark: I think the second line gets the address of the vtable, and the address of the virtual function is not gotten until the call instruction...

Comment: I think you are right Ben - it must be getting the address of the vtable, rather than reading the vtable directly from the address from [x]. Otherwise every object would have a vTable in it rather than pointing to a common vtable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is it the first virtual function in the table, or the first entry in the table? I'm just wondering if the type-info is in the table before/after the virtual function? I am using MSVC

Comment: It must be the first entry in the table, otherwise there would be an offset in the assembly code somewhere. I am not sure where the type info is.

Answer (score 2):

In pseudo-code:

```
(*(*m->__vtbl)[0])(m)
```

Optimized version (can `rcx` be used for indexing?):

```
mov         rcx,qword ptr [x]       ; load rcx with object pointer
mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]     ; load rax with the vtable pointer
call        qword ptr [rax]         ; call through the vtable slot for the virtual function
```

or

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [x]       ; load rax with object pointer
mov         rcx,rax                 ; copy object pointer to rcx (the 'this' pointer)
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax]     ; load rax with the vtable pointer
call        qword ptr [rax]         ; call through the vtable slot for the virtual function
```

Comment: and (*(*m->__vtbl)[0])(m) is effectively a function pointer of void arguments, right? Its just that the pointer comes from an offset calculated by de-referencing a second pointer?

Comment: No, not void parameters. Member functions need a this parameter.

Comment: Forgot that bit! Yes 1 parameter.

Comment: So in the asm- how does the loading of the 'this' argument happen? I cant see anything in the asm comments referring to the passing of a parameter.

Comment: As others have said, the rcx register holds the `this` argument.